# Is it possible to create a progressbar in arc shape in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to create a progressbar in arc shape. should I create a custom view for that? Or with the help of `onDraw()` method of ProgressBar class I can perform this thing? I also want to  add marker on this progressBar like thermometer. Please suggest me any idea. Thanks.

Something like this:

```
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int progress = this.getProgress();
    int maxProgress = this.getMax();

    //calc the progress to angles 
    float angleProgress = progress * 360 / maxProgress;

    //create and set the arc paint 
    Paint arcPaint = new Paint(); 
    arcPaint.setColor(0xff800000); 
    arcPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 
    arcPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    Rect arcRect = new Rect(); this.getDrawingRect(arcRect);
    canvas.drawArc(new RectF(arcRect), -90, angleProgress,true, arcPaint); 
}
```

For ref check this image arc shape progressbar
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY0dq.png]

Comment: What about something like this: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_gauge.html  It is written in Javascript, but uses the HTML5 canvas.  If it was similar, you could get a good understanding of how to draw your widget by looking at its source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ProgressBar widget is not easily customisable, even for significantly less ambitious changes than this. In my opinion, it offers you no valuable behaviours in this context, other than acting as a carrier for minimum, maximum and current values. It also brings with it unwanted functionality such as the 'indeterminate' state.

Create a custom view by extending View and implementing onDraw() - as you have - and onMeasure().